# Creating a binary flag for a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data like -

```
ID    col1
1      a
2      b
3      c
4      d
5      c
```

I wanted to create a binary flag for `col1` such that every distinct value is given 1 but repeating values are tagged as 1 only once. Expected output -

```
ID    col1    Flag
1      a       1 
2      b       1
3      c       1
4      d       1 
5      c       0
```

Order in which 1 occurs for repeating values does not matter. Please help me in this regard. I am not able to take a start for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for set `1` for first duplicated and also unique values:

```
df['Flag'] = np.where(df['col1'].duplicated(), 0, 1)
print (df)
   ID col1  Flag
0   1    a     1
1   2    b     1
2   3    c     1
3   4    d     1
4   5    c     0
```

Another idea with [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html) and inverted mask by `~`:

```
df['Flag'] = (~df['col1'].duplicated()).view('i1')
print (df)
   ID col1  Flag
0   1    a     1
1   2    b     1
2   3    c     1
3   4    d     1
4   5    c     0
```

Comment: Hello Sir...Sir I have readed the documentation of `Series.view`.....but sir what does `'i1'` means here?.....I am supposing i for int and 1?

Comment: @AnuragDabas - ya, it means smallest integer, here `0,1`